# Limiting random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

My question is about limiting r.v.

Suppose, we have a sequence of r.v.s. $\{X_n\}$. And we know that $\liminf X_n=-\infty$ and $\limsup X_n =\infty$ almost surely. What can we say about $\lim X_n$. Does it exist?

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

No, and this really has nothing to do with randomness.  In order for $\lim X_n = L$ to exist, you need $\liminf X_n = \limsup X_n = L$.

Comment: Oh, actually my question arises when trying to justify that $E[\lim X_n]$ does not exist in the context of a simple random walk ($\pm 1$ with equal probabilities). So, the right way of thinking about $\lim X_n$ is that it does not exit. Am I right? Thank's.